# Java Regex Pattern to extract data

Tags: java, regex, data-extraction

I have incoming data something like this

```
http://localhost:1111/search?id=10&time=3200&type=abc
http://localhost:1111/search?time=3200&id=11&type=abc
http://localhost:1111/search?id=12
http://localhost:1111/search?id=13&time=3200&type=abc
```

The data is varying but **not something completely random or unpredictable**.

So basically how do we extract what are the IDs that are incoming in each string ignoring rest of the junk?

Comment: @DaveNewton, I gave sample data. It's not the exact data. :) More or less same phenomenon

Comment: Then it's misleading to show only URLs. Without knowing any of the data's constraints it's difficult to provide concrete advice.

Comment: i don't know how to do substring matching in Java but I'm sure it's there and easy to do with a regex such as the following: `.+?id=(\d+).*?`

Comment: ["Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems."](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Jamie_Zawinski) *Jamie Zawinski*

Comment: @Reddy your sample data seems to suggest you are working with parameters... not sure if you could just work with `ServletRequest` or `HttpServletRequest` objects directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the regex `id=(\d+)` and extract the value of the first [capturing group](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html):

```
String url = "http://localhost:1111/search?id=10&time=3200&type=abc";

Pattern id = Pattern.compile("id=(\\d+)");

Matcher m = id.matcher(url);
if (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
```

```
10
```

See [`Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) and [`Matcher`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).

Comment: This is awesome. Simply works. I always thought Pattern works in some other ways where we need to include complex regex pattern :)

Comment: @Reddy The regex you want seems to be pretty straightforward :) Glad I could help.

Comment: @arashajii, one more help, if I want extract 'type'? I tried similar, is not working.

Comment: @Reddy Well `\d` matches digits, and it looks like type is composed of non-digits as well. You can try `"type=(\\w+)"`.

Answer (score 2):

What if there are several ID's that are passed (which is valid)?

IMHO I wouild rather do somethis more like this:

```
URL url = new URL(<your link>);
String queryString = url.getQuery();
```

parse `queryString` into map for example of `<String,List<String>>` and get the value of `ID` key

Answer (score 1):

`(?<=[?&])id=(\d+)(?=(?:\&|$))`

works in Regex Buddy under the Java and Perl flavor, but not in TextPad, which uses the Boost regex engine. Boost has issues with back-references.

```
(?<=(?:
   [?&]    //PRECEDED BY a question-mark or ampersand
))          
   id=(\d+) //"id=[one-or-more-digits]"
(?=(?:
   \&|$     //FOLLOWED BY an ampersand or the end of the input
))
```

This captures the digits only, and avoids issues such as capturing incorrect fields like

```
anotherid=123sometext
```

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly do you want to use a regular expression to do this?

I would do it like this:

```
String url = "http://localhost:1111/search?id=13&time=3200&type=abc";
     String[] split = url.split("&");
     String id = "";    
     for (String s : split){
         if (s.contains("id")){
             id = s.substring(s.indexOf("id=")+3, s.length());
         }
     }

     System.out.println(id);
```

> 13

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @user1631616's answer:

Here is a sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {         
    URL aURL = new URL("http://localhost:1111/search?id=10&time=3200&type=abc");

    HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    String[] query = aURL.getQuery().split("&");
    for(String s: query) {
        String[] split = s.split("=");
        params.put(split[0],split[1]);
    }
    System.out.println(params.get("id")); 
    System.out.println(params.get("type")); 
    System.out.println(params.get("time")); 

}
```

That way if your HashMap param returns **null** you know that value was not set on the query string.

And also don't have to worry about the ordering of the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do what you want:

(?<=id=)\d+